# AWS Dynamo DB: how to design effectively without GSI

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-design, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am designing the DynamoDB with requirements

1. list all tickets by **user**
2. list all tickets by **ticket type**

My design columns

| p_key | s_key | ticket_type | details | date_created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

primary key: `p_key` (value: `EVENT#<event id>`)

sort key: `s_key`(value: `<user id>#<ticket type>`)

The parameters of query for requirement 1

```
let params = {
    TableName: `eventTable`,
    KeyConditionExpression: ‘p_key = :p_key and begins_with(s_key,  :s_key )‘,
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':p_key': `EVENT#${eventId}`,
      ‘:s_key': `${userId}`,
    }
  };
```

To achieve the requirement 2, I need to add a GSI (For ex: gsi001-index)

primary key: `p_key` (same as above)

sort key: `ticket_type`

the parameters of query as below:

```
let params = {
    TableName: `eventTable`,
    IndexName: ‘gsi001-index’,
    KeyConditionExpression: ‘p_key = :p_key and ticket_type = :ticket_type‘,
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':p_key': `EVENT#${eventId}`,
      ‘:ticket_type’: `${ticketType}`,
    }
  };
```

My question: is there any better design so I don’t need a GSI anymore?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You could do that by introducing duplication into your db - for every item:

> p_key(EVENT#${eventId}), s_key({user_id}#{ticket type}), ticket_type, details, date_created

insert another one with same partition key but sort key changed:

> p_key(EVENT#${eventId}), s_key({ticket_type}#{user_id}), user_id, details, date_created

That way you can support both queries without another GSI.
Disadvantage of this is that modifying any item requires 2 writes. More if you would use [TransactWriteItems](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transactions.html). It depends if your application is write-heavy or read-heavy.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a local secondary index (LSI) when the partition key for the LSI matches the partition key for the table.

Pros

- no additional cost

Cons

- LSIs must be defined when the table is, they can not be added after the fact.
- If an LSI is defined on the table, then there's a 10GB data limit for a given partition key.
- only 5 LSIs allowed per table

[more info](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html)

Comment: very interesting. Thanks a lot. Will look at it